# Python class variables or class variables in general

Tags: python, oop

From Dive into Python:

> Class attributes are available both through direct reference to the
>   class and through any instance of the class.
>
> Class attributes can be used as class-level constants, but they are
>   not really constants. You can also change them.

So I type this into IDLE:

```
IDLE 2.6.5      
>>> class c:
        counter=0


>>> c
<class __main__.c at 0xb64cb1dc>
>>> v=c()
>>> v.__class__
<class __main__.c at 0xb64cb1dc>
>>> v.counter += 1
>>> v.counter
1
>>> c.counter
0
>>>
```

So what am I doing wrong? Why is the class variable not maintaining its value both through direct reference to the class and through any instance of the class.

Comment: Since c.counter is still 0, you obviously did not change its value. You did howver change the value of the counter attribute of the v instance.

Comment: You are looking for "static class variables", I think. Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because ints are immutable in python

```
v.counter += 1
```

rebinds `v.counter` to a new int object. The rebinding creates an instance attribute that masks the class attribute

You can see this happening if you look at the `id()` of `v.counter`

```
>>> id(v.counter)
149265780
>>> v.counter+=1
>>> id(v.counter)
149265768
```

Here you can see that `v` now has a new attribute in its `__dict__`

```
>>> v=c()
>>> v.__dict__
{}
>>> v.counter+=1
>>> v.__dict__
{'counter': 1}
```

Contrast the case where `counter` is mutable, eg a `list`

```
>>> class c:
...  counter=[]
... 
>>> v=c()
>>> v.counter+=[1]
>>> c.counter
[1]
>>>
```

Comment: I would word it: a new int object... to `v.counter`

Answer (score 0):

Your are confused between **declaration** and **instantiation**.

C is the name of a class you declared.

v is an object, instantiated from c.

Comment: That's not the confusion here. If you set a variable on a class, you can read it just fine in exactly the manner above: instance.classvariable.

Answer (score 0):

Before:

```
c.counter = 0
v.counter -> c.counter
```

During:

```
c.counter = 0
v.counter = c.counter + 1
```

After:

```
c.counter = 0
v.counter = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can still get at the class value:

```
v.__class__.__dict__['counter']
```

will allow you to read or set to your class, even if you have obscured the symbol by adding a symbol to your instance's __dict__.